# When is the solution to a convolution equation unique?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I encountered a question I'm not entirely sure how to address.

Suppose $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and further that $f*g = h$.

For known $f$ and known $h$, when is the unknown solution $g$ unique?

The Fourier and inverse-Fourier transform can be taken of both sides to solve for $g,$ as $F^{-1}(F(h)/F(f))$ but without establishing uniqueness, there still may multiple or infinite solutions.

Comment: For instance, if for some $\omega$, $H(\omega) = F(\omega) = 0$, then $G(\omega)$ can be anything, given that $F, G, H$ are the Fourier transforms of $f, g, h$.

Comment: I don't follow the last sentence. If we _could_ say $g=F^{-y}(F(h)/F(f))$ that would show that $g$ was unique. But in fact we can't say that, because as the other comment points out, $F(f)$ may vanish somewhere. When is the solution unique? If and only if the set where $F(f)=0$ has empty interior, I suspect

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think that's acceptable, that there may be multiple inverses over different intervals, as long as it's not uncountably many.